# Whether I will be allowed to enter Europe with year long Schengen Visa when my UK BRP is expiring in 50 days

Tags: immigration, uk-visa, indian-citizens

I am an Indian working on Tier 2 Visa in UK. My BRP is valid till 26th April, 2019.
I have Schengen Visa which valid until December, 2019 and I got this visa in London itself.

I am planning for a trip to France and Germany in March, 2019 and wanted to check if I can travel to Europe for 10 days when my UK BRP is valid only for another 50 days.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a valid Schengen Visa, that can be used until it becomes invalid.

If the **issuing conditions** were based on the validity of your **UK BRP**, then the Schengen Visa validity would would be the same as the BRP.

When actually entering the Schengen Area, the border guard (independent of visa validity) will make the final decision if you may enter or not

- not being allowed to return to the UK and **not** planing to return to your home country

may be a reason to refuse entry.

You should take this aspect into consideration before leaving the UK.